# Как узнать id потока на котором в данный момент исполняется горутина?

Tags: golang

Как узнать id потока на котором в данный момент исполняется горутина?

Comment: Возможно [так](https://blog.sgmansfield.com/2015/12/goroutine-ids/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала нужно определиться с тем, что вы называете ID потока. Есть идентификатор в `pthreads`, есть идентификатор потока в ядре Линукса, есть идентификатор потока в ядре Windows.

В любом случае нужно вызывать соответствующую Сишную функцию. Например, в Линуксе для этого есть системный вызов [`gettid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettid). Для него в Golang предусмотрена [обёртка](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#Gettid) в пакете `syscall`. Соответственно, вот пример программы, которая печатает линуксовый идентификатор потока для `main` и для сотни порождённых горутин:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
)

func print_thread_id(info string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    tid := syscall.Gettid()
    fmt.Printf("%s: Thread ID: %v\n", info, tid)
    if wg != nil {
        wg.Done()
    }
}

func main() {
    print_thread_id("main", nil)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go print_thread_id(fmt.Sprintf("goroutine %d", i+1), &wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Вывод у неё примерно вот какой:

```
main: Thread ID: 2804
goroutine 2: Thread ID: 2806
goroutine 5: Thread ID: 2806
goroutine 4: Thread ID: 2806
goroutine 7: Thread ID: 2806
goroutine 1: Thread ID: 2808
goroutine 10: Thread ID: 2808

...

goroutine 83: Thread ID: 2807
goroutine 46: Thread ID: 2807
goroutine 88: Thread ID: 2816
goroutine 93: Thread ID: 2809
goroutine 98: Thread ID: 2804
goroutine 84: Thread ID: 2807
goroutine 99: Thread ID: 2816
goroutine 94: Thread ID: 2806
```

Comment: А могу я как то получить ID всех потоков захваченных планировщиком go?

Comment: @DenverToha Ну-у-у... Вы можете через `getpid` получить идентификатор текущего процесса, а затем в `/proc/<pid>/task/` посмотреть поддиректории с цифровыми именами. Например, для программы из моего ответа получилось вот что: `ls /proc/5853/task/` `5853  5854  5855  5856  5857  5858  5859  5860`. Этот способ даст вам все потоки процесса, но нет гарантии, что рантайм go запускает горутины в каждом из этих потоков. Как понять, какие именно потоки используются для горутин, я не знаю.